# Como determina time() la zona horaria de forma predeterminada PHP

Tags: php, timestamp, time

Me ha surgido esta duda a raíz de estar trabajando con fechas. El problema es el siguiente; obteniendo la hora actual desde la función `getdate()` que toma de la función `time()` me devuelve una hora que no tiene nada que ver con mi zona horaria (UTC+0) y al utilizar la función 'date_default_timezone_get()' para ver la zona horaria por defecto me devuelve Europe/Berlin (UTC+1)

Buscando en la documentación de PHP he encontrado este apéndice [Soporte de fecha/hora](http://php.net/manual/es/migration51.datetime.php) donde se define como determinan la zona horaria.

En base a esto creo que la zona horaria la está determinando y cito;

> Suposición "mágica" (si lo permite el sistema operativo)

ya que no he seteado la zona horaria, la variable de entorno TZ no esta definida en mi sistema operativo (esto no estoy seguro del todo pero lo he revisado en la configuración avanzada de windows 10) y que la zona horaria que me devuelve no es igual a la UTC.

¿De donde saca esta "suposición mágina" la zona horaria?

Comment: lo de la zona horaria te va a retornar la zona donde se encuentre tu server, podrías utilizar las bases de datos de ***maxmin*** para determinar la zona horaria del usuario en función de su IP, yo las uso y va de lujo, me reconoce las zonas horarias de donde ingresan los usuarios al sistema.

Comment: Lo zona horaria de php se toma del archivo php.ini, que por default como mencionas viene configurado con: Europe/Berlin. Puedes cambiarlo agregando en tus scripts algo como: date_default_timezone_set('America/Cancun'); O en su caso tambien lo puedes hacer directamente en el php.ini buscando la linea: date.timezone=America/Cancun

Comment: Modifica la zona horaria en tu php.ini. No digo que sea tu caso, pero solo lo menciono, es que si estás trabajando con WordPress, este maneja internamente su propio tiempo. Para acceder a la hora que está manejando el blog, puedes usar la función current_time() https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time

Comment: Mi intención era conocer de donde tomaba la función la zona horaria sin haberla seteado,  y efectivamente está en el fichero php.ini. Mi servidor está en local y por eso me confundía que me devolviera esa zona. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para especificar la Zona horaria para cuestiones de formato debes configurarlo en tu archivo **php.ini**, buscando la linea que dice `date.timezone = America/El_Salvador` por ejemplo, luego reiniciar tu servidor para que coja los cambios.

Fijate que no este comentada con ";" si lo tiene debes quitarselo

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola, muy buenas! Este problema se puede solucionar así:

Primero tienes que saber cuál es la zona horaria en la que está configurado tu servidor por medio de:

> `date_default_timezone_get()` -> [Ir a la página de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)

Una vez que ya sabes la zona horaria determinada por defecto en tu servidor, tienes que establecer la zona que tú quieres, por medio de

> `date_default_timezone_set()` -> [Ir a la página de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Si no te cambió la zona horaria, tienes que ir al archivo php.ini y en la línea donde dice `date.timezone` pones la zona horaria que es la misma que habías determinado en `date_default_timezone_set()`.

Para saber cuál es tu zona horaria, tienes que buscarlo en el [ápendice de zonas horarias de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.php)

Comment: gracias por el apoyo, pero poner solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad y eventualmente recibirás votos negativos

Comment: añade lo relavente de la página aqui y conserva el enlace como referencia

Comment: Okey perfecto, soy nuevo en esto. Muchas gracias por avisar! :) Borro la respuesta entonces?

Comment: @WalterDona no borres la respuesta, pero edítala para indicar cómo se configuraría la zona horario del servidor a partir de la información enlazada. Lee [answer] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Hola! Ahí modifiqué la respuesta! espero que esté bien formulada, me esforcé bastante en poner la mayor información posible y lo más legible también. El último enlace de los apéndices de zonas horarias pienso que es útil para el aporte. Les agradezco sus consejos, es muy lindo formar parte de esta comunidad :) Saludos!